# How can I start phone emulator on HyperV or share phone through RDP?

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, rdp, hyper-v

I want to see how far I can take my Surface 2 for developing in Visual Studio 2013. Please note that this is a Surface 2 running WinRT - not full version.

**Here is my setup**

Surface 2 on desktop mode with RDP.
Windows 2012 running HyperV with a Windows 8.1 VM.
On the Windows 8.1 VM I have installed VS 2013. Naturally, HyperV gets installed as well.

**My problems**

1. My first thought was that I could use the Emulator but it complains that it **failed to start because some of the Hyper-V components are not running**. After some research this seems to be the result of Hyper-V in Hyper-V.
2. Then I tried to use an alternate approach. To share my Windows Phone through USB. I inserted my "Nokia Lumia 1020" in USB port of Surface 2. I could then see it in my desktop. Also, when I started RDP application I could see "Nokia Lumia 1020" under Local resources->Other supported Plug and Play devices. I checked it for sharing. I connected again but the phone was not visible on the guest operating system.

Anyone else done this? Either know how to circumvent the Hyper-V in Hyper-V or share the phone for development (through RDP).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use hyper-v without windows 8 pro, I'm sorry... Try nokia's device rdp (http://developer.nokia.com/resources/remote-device-access) ...